# git update-index --assume-unchanged unsuccess

Tags: git

this is my git code

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged conf/con.java
```

but,if I am try to perform a pull

```
git pull
```

the con.java will be changed, So how can I approach this issue?
i do not want this file(con.java) to be changed while executing git pull.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the other update-index option:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged -- a file
git update-index --skip-worktree -- a file
```

From what I have seen in "[Difference Between '`assume-unchanged`' and '`skip-worktree`'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23806990/6309)", it should better resist to `git pull`.